# How to compile imgui source files using gcc

Tags: c++, makefile

How do you compile `imgui` source files with gcc

According to `build_win32` in one of the examples in the repo

```
@REM Build for Visual Studio compiler. Run your copy of vcvars32.bat or vcvarsall.bat to setup command-line compiler.
@set OUT_DIR=Debug
@set OUT_EXE=example_win32_directx11
@set INCLUDES=/I..\.. /I..\..\backends /I "%WindowsSdkDir%Include\um" /I "%WindowsSdkDir%Include\shared" /I "%DXSDK_DIR%Include"
@set SOURCES=main.cpp ..\..\backends\imgui_impl_dx11.cpp ..\..\backends\imgui_impl_win32.cpp ..\..\imgui*.cpp
@set LIBS=/LIBPATH:"%DXSDK_DIR%/Lib/x86" d3d11.lib d3dcompiler.lib
mkdir %OUT_DIR%
cl /nologo /Zi /MD %INCLUDES% /D UNICODE /D _UNICODE %SOURCES% /Fe%OUT_DIR%/%OUT_EXE%.exe /Fo%OUT_DIR%/ /link %LIBS%
```

the first three lines are not important since they define the output directory and the output executable, next is the `INCLUDES` which I included in my `Makefile`, next is the source files which I also added but for some reason does not work as expected

```
CC = g++
FILES =  main.cpp C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\imgui\\backend\\imgui_impl_dx11.cpp C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\imgui\\backend\\imgui_impl_win32.cpp C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\imgui\\backend\\imgui*.cpp
INCLUDES = -I C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\my-project\\Include  -ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler

build: $(FILES)
    $(CC) $(FILES) $(INCLUDES)
```

The `Includes` folder contains all the header files from the folder `backend`

this is what I get when I run the command `make`

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\imgui\\backend\\imgui_impl_dx11.cpp', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

why do I get this error?

Comment: ``\\`` -> ``\``, or better `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP said works AFTER changing the command to include `-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`:

```
g++ -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ $IMGUI_DIR/main.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/backends/imgui_impl_dx11.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/backends/imgui_impl_win32.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/imgui*.cpp -I $IMGUI_DIR -I $IMGUI_DIR/backends   -ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler -lgdi32  -ldwmapi
```

`$IMGUI_DIR` can be replaced by the path to the `main.cpp` of any example or your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more of a thank you to HolyBlackCat for helping
I used `MSYS2`shell to compile with `MINGW64` environment
after cloning the repo to the Desktop I used

```
export $IMGUI_DIR=C:/Users/test/Desktop/imgui
```

this makes the final command shorter and gives the variable `IMGUI_DIR` the path of the imgui repo
next
we run the command

```
g++  main.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/backends/imgui_impl_dx11.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/backends/imgui_impl_win32.cpp $IMGUI_DIR/imgui*.cpp -I $IMGUI_DIR -I $IMGUI_DIR/backends   -ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler -lgdi32  -ldwmapi
```

where

`main.cpp` is your code (the example to be used)

`$IMGUI_DIR/imgui.cpp` includes all source files of `imgui`

`-I $IMGUI_DIR` includes header files in the imgui folder

`-I $IMGUI_DIR/backends` includes backend header files

`-ld3d11 -ld3dcompiler -lgdi32  -ldwmapi` links windows libraries needed for

`imgui` to work